# Breadcrumb wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a breadcrumb on my page as the user walks down a directory structure but I want to prevent the breadcrumb from wrapping onto a new line if it gets too long and instead start shortening the path.

To go from

```
Home / Folder 1 / Folder 2
/ File
```

to

```
Home / ... / Folder 2 / File
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vhhH/4/

Actually altering the text isn't the real problem, it's detecting when the breadcrumb has wrapped and triggering the code to do the text replacement when someone resizes the window.

Update:

Here's what I ended up with if it's of use to future searchers

http://jsfiddle.net/6vhhH/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check the height of your breadcrumb when the page resizes:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($("#breadcrumb").height() > singleLineValue) {
         // change
    } else {
         // change back
    }
}):
```

where 'breadcrumb' is the id of a wrapper around your breadcrumb (nav or div as you please)

Comment: That seems to be the start of it.  I think when I finish it'll be more complicated than just and if else block though to cater for shrinking a little bit.

Comment: I'm choosing this as the better answer as it put me more on the right track to something that was flexible.

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of this answer - http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/wN7ah/ and some added code I have a **solution for you - http://jsfiddle.net/6vhhH/7/**

Basically i've done the following:

- Made the breadcrumb not wrap and overflow hidden.
- I added a 1px dot to the last `<li>`
- Script then checks if that element is off the page.

Click the window to get the result.

Comment: I quite like this but it does limit to checking against the size of the window.In a less simple example with more content added to the right of the breadcrumb trail would this still work without also having to take into account the sizes of those dynamic objects as well?

Comment: This is as flexible as you want it to be, just change line 28 to the wrapper of your choice. See this example - http://jsfiddle.net/6vhhH/11/